# Powershell script runs on a Win7 client but not on an Exchange CAS server

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I have created a small powershell script to disable active sync for mailboxes when the user is not a member of a specific AD group. This script works perfectly when running it from my Windows 7 workstation from the Exchange Management Shell. It does not however work on the CAS server's EMS.

```
$groupname = "ActiveSync Users"
$groupidentity = $(Get-Group $groupname).Identity.DistinguishedName
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited |Set-CASMailbox -ActiveSyncEnabled $false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
$users = Get-ADGroupMember $groupname | select -ExpandProperty name
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-Mailbox $user | Set-CASMailbox -ActiveSyncEnabled $true
}
```

Both the `Get-Mailbox | Set-CASMailbox` and the `Get-ADGroupMember` parts of the code fail on the Exchange CAS server. The `Get-Mailbox | Set-CASMailbox` lists warnings that no settings have been modified for every user account. The `Get-ADGroupMember` is erroring as a non recognized cmdlet.

It looks like either a permissions error or some dependancy is missing from the Exchange server, but I'm unsure of where to look to see what is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is `Get-ADGroupMember`. You need to load the Active Directory snap-in with the command `import-module ActiveDirectory`. You'll need to have the "Active Directory module for Windows PowerShell" feature installed on your Exchange server for this to work.

The Get/Set commands give you that warning because your script does this:

1. Disable all ActiveSync users.
2. Populate $users (this is failing)
3. Enable ActiveSync for users in $users

Since you've run the script once already, step 1 has already been completed. Running it again gives you the "no changes" warning. Fix step 2 and your script will work. Note you'll still get that warning for mailboxes that already have ActiveSync turned off, but at least you won't get it for EVERY mailbox like you are now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, importing that module did the trick. I do still get the warnings on the server but not the client, but the script does appear to be working as intended now.